# Type parameter for classes implementing trait disregarding trait parameters

Tags: scala, types, traits, type-parameter

I have a trait with type parameters and it has a list containing instances of another classes implementing this trait. I don't care about type paramaters of those instances, so I try to define a type that would allow any subclass implementing the trait with whatever type parameters.

```
trait Synchronizable[A,B] {
  type S <: Synchronizable[_,_]

  val slaves: MutableList[S]

  def synchronizeWith(q: S) = {
    if (!slaves.contains(q)) slaves += q
  }

}
```

But it won't compile due to some particular instance doesn't conform to this type definition.

```
[error]  found   : TwoBuffers.this.faster.type (with underlying type model.collection.SynchronizableTimeSeriesBuffer[someCaseClass ,Option[Any]])
[error]  required: TwoBuffers.this.slower.S
[error]     slower.synchronizeWith(faster)
```

Comment: also the question is if something like this is possible at all

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not clear from your question how you are using this trait. I think you might want something like this:

```
trait Synchronizable[A,B] {
  type S = Synchronizable[_, _] // Note =, not <:

  val slaves = MutableList.empty[S] // Create list in trait.

  def synchronizeWith(q: S) = {
    if (!slaves.contains(q)) slaves += q
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you really need to use the `type S <: Synchronizable[_, _]` declaration, then you will need to override the `type` statement in a sub-class. For example:

```
trait Synchronizable[A,B] {
  type S <: Synchronizable[_, _]

  val slaves = MutableList.empty[S] // Create list in trait.

  def synchronizeWith(q: S) = {
    if (!slaves.contains(q)) slaves += q
  }
}

class SomeClass[A, B]
extends Synchronizable[A, B] {
  override type S = SomeClass[_, _]
}
```

Comment: I wrote a bit more about the case. Please have a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198177/akka-synchronizing-timestamped-messages-from-several-actors